Alpine.js it's ssr or ssg framework?
I have a question about apline.js . Sorry if it's stupid, but I didn't find answer in the off documentation. What kind of rendering does apline.js?
I understand that he doesn't have a v-dom, but I find topics about ssr rendering option on apline.js thanks for your attention.
